# How to create uncompressed PDF file?

Tags: c#, itext

An unorthodox question for sure. :-) During development testing, I'd prefer to create uncompressed, non-binary PDF files with iTextSharp so that I can check their internals easily. I can always convert the finished PDF with various utilities but that takes an extra step that would be comfortable to avoid. There are some places (eg. PdfImage) where I can decide about compression level but I couldn't find anything about the compression used to output the individual PDF objects into the stream. Do you think this is possible with iTextSharp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

**[1.] Disable compression for all your documents at once:**

Please take a look at the `Document` class. You'll find:

```
public static bool Compress = true;
```

If you change this `static bool` to `false`, PDF syntax streams won't be compressed.

Of course: images will are de facto compressed. For instance: if you add a JPEG to your document, you are adding an image that is already compressed, and iText won't *uncompress* it.

**[2.] Disable compression for a single document at a time:**

Please take a look at the `PdfWriter` class. You'll find:

```
protected internal int compressionLevel = PdfStream.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;
```

If you change the value of `compressionLevel` to `PdfStream.NO_COMPRESSION` before opening the ´document´, your PDF syntax streams won't be compressed.

Comment: Seems it needs to be `Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION` now (from `java.util.zip.Deflater`).